# Servo Controllers, Servos, Power consumption

Tags: pi-4, power, servo

I'm looking at options for controlling multiple Servos I keep finding the same board, the [PCA9685](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ANGEEK-PCA9685-Channel-Interface-Raspberry/dp/B07V72VBJ4/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=PCA9685&qid=1596814323&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzUkRCOEdMRUNVQVJRJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwOTg2NTY1M0pTMVM2U0hIOVVFWiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNDk1MDQ2MU1XT0NIRVM0QjEwVSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=)

Which is great, I see people using them for those small 9g servos, but what about servos that pull close to an amp or more each? Is such a controller suitable for that?

I've read that the external power supply pins are directly connected to the V+ and ground pins at the bottom for each servo. So if I wanted to, could I just use the PWM signals from this board and connect the servos' supply voltage outside of the board (I don't like the idea of running more than 2-3 amps through those traces!) keeping a common ground?

Answer (score 1):

I agree.  I wouldn't trust more than a couple of amps through the copper traces of the typical modules incorporating the PCA9685 chip.

Separate power supplies will work.  Remember you will still need to connect the PCA9685 module ground to the power supply/servo ground.

As an aside my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library will generate suitable servo pulses direct from the Pi.